# Software for comparing two different text or html files

Tags: windows, text-processing

I need a software that can do the following:

1. Compare two different files
2. Highlight the differences
3. Can handle big text files

I have already checked out [diffchecker](https://www.diffchecker.com/).

My OS is Windows 7.

Comment: For what OS should that be? Any price limit when it comes to paid solutions?

Comment: @Izzy OS is Windows 7. I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) is my personal favourite:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- Never had a problem with big text files.

Answer (score 2):

[Meld](http://meldmerge.org). Cross platform (Win/Linux). I use it to clean hacked WordPress websites. Works on text files at least 128415 [lines long](http://norvig.com/big.txt)

Answer (score 2):

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/downloads/?lang=en)

- It can also compare folders.
- Has a portable version

Answer (score 2):

#### Beyond Compare

It worked fine for me on windows with huge log (text) files, like more than 400 MB each. [Beyond Compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/index.php)

Key features:

- Highlighting diff, also with different themes
- Handles most of the filetypes
- Integrates well with git
- Cross platform (Win-Mac-Linux)

Contra:

- Need to purchase

Comment: I concur, it's the best I have come across.  It will also do **FTP** to your websites (for instance) and can be used as **GIT** comparer.  It's really not that expensive.  I have no affiliation with Scooter Software.

Answer (score 1):

TotalCommander (freeware) includes a good file diff feature:

https://www.ghisler.com/

Comment: And how does it meet the requirements – especially handling big files?